# сброс пароля от git в idea

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Не могу сбросить пароль, в настройках идеи выставлял "не сохранять пароли при перезапуске" файлик с паролями чистил, но так и не дает мне ввести новый логин и пароль.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

После выбора этого пункта в настройках

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо очистить кэш idea. Для этого есть следующий пункт:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого пароль должен сброситься